# How to import CSV File using String.split(",") without having the array shortened due to blank fields?

Tags: java, csv, split, string

Currently, when I import the CSV file line by line with `String.split(",")` if there is a line that looks like `"foo,,bar,,fizz,,,"` the method returns an array of length 5, which looks like `["foo", "", "bar, "", "fizz"]`. How do I get the method to return an array of length 8 being `["foo", "", "bar", "", "fizz, "", "", ""]`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is another [overload of `split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) that achieves that:

```
string.split(",", -1);
```

Comment: You are simply the best. Thank you!

Comment: Also see `StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens` for a cleaner API.